# Azure Video Indexer - Azure Media Service

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

i've created an azure video indexer that is related to a media service account.
Add to it i've created a storage account to media service. I've uploaded the video in it but when i go on azure video indexer portal the video is not exist. How they share the storage (video indexer and media services)?

Thanks for collaborating

I don't find anything about that....

Answer (score 1):

You won't see any videos uploaded to the storage account in Video Indexer because it works the other way around. What you need to do is upload your video through Video Indexer and Video Indexer will store it on the connected storage account. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/upload-index-videos?tabs=With-classic-account

Answer (score 1):

I could be missing something but you still need to upload the video through the Azure Video Indexer website - Video Indexer doesnt automatically pull all files from the storage account.
See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/upload-index-videos?tabs=With-classic-account).

Thanks,
David